# Using the watershed function designed by Emgu.Cv in C#

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have added Emgu.Cv files to my project and I want to use it's watershed function but I dont't know how to use this. Can any one help me and explain the function,it's arguments and it's return?

Comment: Are you referring to the following: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/259ba717-fc88-a05c-cbd1-640a82dcc7bb.htm ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is some vanilla code that makes use of watershed function on a generic input image using emgucv:

```
public void TestWaterShed()
          {  
             Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>("myImage.jpg");                 
             Image<Gray, Int32> marker = new Image<Gray, Int32>(image.Width, image.Height);
             Rectangle rect = image.ROI;
             marker.Draw(
                new CircleF(
                   new PointF(rect.Left + rect.Width / 2.0f, rect.Top + rect.Height / 2.0f),
                   (float)(Math.Min(image.Width, image.Height) / 4.0f)),
                new Gray(255),
                0);
             CvInvoke.cvWatershed(image, marker);
          }
```

Comment: Thanks alot.I tried your code but When showing marker as an image it's white and nothing in it.How can I have the image made by watershed?I mean the image which is segmented.Thanks agaim in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer to the following question:

[watershed function provided by EmguCv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11015100/1453654)

You need to set the values of the mask file to zero (use `cvZero` for that). Use a second reference circle (preferably with a different greyvalue) and then retrieve the result from your mask file, after converting it to a greyvalue image.