# watershed function provided by EmguCv

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv, watershed

I want to use watershed function provided by emgucv.I used the following code but all I get is a white picture.Please help me and correct this code.Thanks.

```
Image im;
    Bitmap bm;
    Bitmap bmF;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//setting the background image
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            im = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
           bm = new Bitmap(im);

        }
        panel1.BackgroundImage = im;
        panel1.Width = im.Width;
        panel1.Height = im.Height;
        panel1.Visible = true;


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        watershed(bm);
    }

    private void watershed(Bitmap bm)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> imWa = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bm);
        Image<Gray, Int32> imgr = new Image<Gray, int>(imWa.Width, imWa.Height);
        Rectangle rec = imWa.ROI;
        imgr.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(rec.Left + rec.Width / 2.0f, rec.Top + rec.Height / 2.0f), (float)(Math.Min(imWa.Width, imWa.Height) / 4.0f)), new Gray(255), 0);
        CvInvoke.cvWatershed(imWa, imgr);
        bmF=new Bitmap(bm.Width,bm.Height);
        bmF= imgr.ToBitmap();
        panel1.BackgroundImage = (Image)bmF;
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: What headers did you include to get the `Bitmap` data type?

Answer (score 2):

You need to better prepare your mask file for the watershed (i.e. imgr).

For this purpose you need to set all to zero first. You can do that by calling:

```
CvInvoke.cvZero(imgr);
```

Then you should introduce at least a second "class". Hence you could draw a second circle with different coordinates (something belonging to the background). To be on the safe side use a different greyvalue for the first cirle (e.g. `new Gray(100)`) than for the second one (e.g. `new Gray(200)`).

You will get your result in your mask file imgr at the end, with the two classes showing in different greyvalues.

I am not really sure you need the ROI bit...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
bmF= imgr.ToBitmap();
```

Try this:

```
bmF= imgr.Convert<Gray,byte>().ToBitmap();
```